# Error in U-SQL Job on Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have lots of json files in my Azure Data Lake account. They are organized as: Archive -> Folder 1 -> JSON Files.

What I want to do is extract a particular field: timestamp from each json and then then just put it in a csv file.

My issue is:

I started with this script:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM "correct_path/Assemblies/JSON/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
CREATE ASSEMBLY IF NOT EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM "correct_path/Assemblies/JSON/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

DECLARE @INPUT_FILE string = @"correct_path/Tracking_3e9.json";


//Extract the different properties from the Json file using a JsonExtractor
@json =
    EXTRACT Partition string, Custom string
    FROM @INPUT_FILE
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();


OUTPUT @json
TO "correct_path/Output/simple.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

1. I get error:

   E_STORE_USER_FILENOTFOUND: File not found or access denied

But I do have access to the file in the data explorer of the Azure Data Lake, so how can it be?

2. I don't want to run it for each file one by one. I just want to give it all the files in a folder (like Tracking*.json) or just a bunch of folders (like Folder*) and it should go through them and put the output for each file in a single row of the output csv.

Haven't found any tutorials on this.

3. Right now, I am reading the entire json, how to read just one field like time stamp which is a field within a particular field, like data : {timestamp:"xxx"}?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Not sure why you're running into that error without more information - are you specifically missing the input file or is it the assemblies?

2) You can use a fileset to extract data from a set of files. Just use {} to denote the wildcard character in your input string, and then save that character in a new column.  So for example, your input string could be @"correct_path/{day}/{hour}/{id}.json", and then your extract statement becomes:

```
    EXTRACT
        column1 string,
        column2 string,
        day     int,
        hour    int,
        id      int
   FROM @input
```

3) You'll have to read the entire JSON in your SELECT statement, but you can refine it down to only the rows you want in future rowsets. For example:

```
    @refine=
        SELECT timestamp FROM @json;

     OUTPUT @refine
     ...
```

It sounds like some of your JSON data is nested however (like the timestamp field).  You can find information on our GitHub ([Using the JSON UDFs](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats)) and in [this blog](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2017/9/4/querying-multi-structured-json-files-with-u-sql-in-azure-data-lake) for how to read nested JSON data.
Hope this helps, and please let me know if you have additional questions!

Comment: Thanks, that error is gone now, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137679/usql-query-to-create-a-table-from-json-data this question. I want to just create a table with every json name-value pair...as a column in the table: e.g. if System: Data is a pair I need a column as System and the value of a row for that column will be = Data. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andy, I just responded to that question you linked - can you let me know if that solution works for you? If not, we can work further on your specific case!