# USQL Query to create a Table from Json Data

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a json which is like `[{}, {}, {}]`, i.e. there can be multiple rows and each row has a number of property - value pairs, which remain fixed for each row.

```
@json =
    EXTRACT MainId string, Details string
    FROM @INPUT_FILE
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();
```

This gives me json as a string.

I don't know how to get: `row[3].property4` things like a property's value of a given row. Complicating things the properties are all themselves arranged as {Name: "XXX", Value: "YYY"}

```
@jsonnodes =
    SELECT JsonApp.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(@json, "event", "id") AS json_map
    FROM @json;
```

Now, the above query I tried but it did not work.

It gives me the error:

```
Rowset variable '@json' is not a scalar variable.
```

How could I get row-property pairs and put them in a csv file or table?

Thanks for your help.

The JSON looks like:

```
[{"MainId":"24201803","System":[{"Name":"event","Value":"S"},{"Name":"id","Value":""}],
"Details":[{"Name":"EventName","Value":"W"},{"Name":"previd","Value":"88"}],
"ttl":8640000}, ....Multiple Rows of the Same type as before....]
```

The output I am trying to get is:

Table Columns = MainId | System.event | System.id | Details.EventName | Details.previd | ttl

The table's rows' values will be filled by rows having the corresponding property's values (as in the json rows).

Comment: Can you please post an example json input file? Then we can recreate the situation.

Comment: @PeterBons hi peter I have posted a sample json

Comment: Ok, and to check things, `Details` is just another array like `System` and `Custom`? Can you post the desired result based on the example input? Because the "event", "id" and "message" are not present in the example json. So I do not exactly know what kind of csv you expect.

Comment: @PeterBons yes, I have made a few changes in the question t make the examples consistent...i just took thing from different queries earlier...I have also posted the desired result ...please let me know if any other detail would help in ascertaining the solution..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution below that worked in my small test case - I agree that the {"Name: 'XXX', Value: 'YYY'} formatting makes things a little tricky but you can still get this done without a custom extractor - just lots of nested JSON.

Basically, you extract a SQLArray from the System and Details JSON (in @parse_json), then split those into smaller JSON tuples (in @get_nested), and then finally extract the "Values" in @output. See code below. Let me know if you have questions!

```
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]
    FROM @FormatsAssembly;

    CREATE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json]
    FROM @JSONAssembly;

    REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
    REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

    DECLARE @CommentsPath = "/JSONTest/rawJson.json";


    @get_json =
        EXTRACT 
            MainId          int,
            System          string,
            Details         string,
            ttl             int
        FROM @CommentsPath
        USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();


    @parse_json =
        SELECT MainId, 
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(System).Values AS SystemJson,
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(Details).Values AS DetailsJson,
               ttl
        FROM @get_json;


    @get_nested =
        SELECT 
               MainId,
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(SystemJson[0]) AS SystemName,
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(SystemJson[1]) AS SystemId,
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(DetailsJson[0]) AS DetailsName,
               Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(DetailsJson[1]) AS DetailsPrevid,
               ttl
        FROM @parse_json;

    @output =
        SELECT MainId,
               SystemName["Value"] AS SystemEvent,
               SystemId["Value"] AS SystemId,
               DetailsName["Value"] AS EventName,
               DetailsPrevid["Value"] AS PrevId,
               ttl
        FROM @get_nested;

    OUTPUT @output 
        TO @"/JSONTest/test1.csv"
        USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had one more question: suppose the script encounters a file where a particluar field is null... or say the file itself is empty..how can i handle those cases in the script? I am sure this must not be a if..else situation as these issues come up frequently in data anlsysis. Again, thanks a ot for the help.

Comment: Since the JSON extractor is technically custom code I can't guarantee it handles all edge causes but I ran a few quick tests and it handles empty files and missing keys with no errors (outputs empty file or leaves filed empty).  If you're using the default extractors, you can use the silent flag to ignore any failed rows (ex: Extractors.Csv(silent: true)). The default extractors also handle empty files just fine.  For null values, U-SQL follows C# semantics: non-object types are non-nullable by default but can be made nullable with a ? (ex: int?), while object types are implicitly nullable.

Comment: mabasile_MSFT thanks, what if say I write code for 3 values to be xtracted from JSON -- the middle one is missing...then when I output the values..wont I get the wrong values as say, value 3 will appear in place of value 1?

Comment: (Same disclaimer as above that I can't guarantee edge cases but) it looks like the JSON extractor is smart enough to know when it can't find a column, and will  leave an empty value in it's place. So if you're extracting MainId, System, Details, and ttl and your JSON file only contains {"MainId: "foo", "Details":"bar", "TTL": "1"}, your output (in a .csv file for example) will be "foo",,"bar",1

Comment: @mabasile_MSFT say the first field MainId is itself missing , then the json extractor will work? Or i say instead of 3 fields only 1 field is present, like TTL, so will the extractor detect that MainId and Details are missing and that only TTL is present and hence, MainID and Details should be empty? Only TTL field should be filled, but will it be filled as MainId or Details or TTL? That is my issue here. Any way I can dynamicall name the columns in this line: SystemName["Value"] AS SystemEvent, ? Thanks .

Comment: @mabasile_MSFT plz take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403728/u-sql-vertex-fail-fast-error. thanks.