# U-SQL Job Failing

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a USQL Script which works fine for a single file.

I put some ?? operators in the query to account for missing data cases too.

Now, when I ran it on about 900 JSON files:

```
TooManyVertexFailedInStage: Too many vertex failures in a stage
E_RUNTIME_USER_EXPRESSIONEVALUATION: Error while evaluating expression Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(tmp_0[0])["Value"] ?? "0"

Component
JobManager_User

Message
Too many vertex failures in a stage

Description
Many vertices in stage SV1_Extract failed due to Vertex user code error.
Details
Vertex SV1_Extract[4613].v0 {9199FFCE-F114-47D1-912E-D5FFBAC11E0C} failed 

Error:
Vertex user code error

exitcode=CsExitCode_StillActive Errorsnippet=
```

I am not getting the cause of the error?

And how could I resolve it?

Comment: Could you post a copy of the script you're running as well?

Comment: @mabasile_MSFT it is very similar to the script from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137679/usql-query-to-create-a-table-from-json-data/49179243#49179243 in the answer

Comment: Please check that you have the lastest version of the ADL Tools so you get the full error message. Also, it would be very useful to have a simple repro case we can run on our own account. If you are concerned about data privacy, create a simple example JSON document that is complex enough to show what  you want to achieve, yet simple enough to create a simple to understand repro.

Comment: @MichaelRys Hi Michael, I have provided a simple example JSON that is close enough to the actual data. and a sample output in other questions as well. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your script locally you should see more detailed error information in the console output.  Without knowing what your code does, it's hard to infer the error but it could be that tmp_0 is null, or is of zero length, or has a zeroth element that doesn't have a property called value.  Your ?? operator wouldn't help with any of these cases.