# Checking Condition on a U-SQL RowSet

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a simple use case. I want to filter data based on whether a json file contains some fields named something like "event".

I have data which can have 1, 2, 3 or any number of json arrays.

The arrays have json objects in them.

So, consider I have 4 arrays: [A], [B], [C], [D]

I can extract them in U-SQL with JSON Extractor. Then get the array values as JSONTuple.

Once these are extracted. I want to check if an array has a particular json field.

Like: `select @data where JsonContains(A, "ordernumber") .`

How can I do that in USQL? The simple way to do:

```
Select [A], [B], [c], [D] where A constains "event" ...
```

I tried doing but there is no way to do like in sql. Please help. Thanks.

Aas a side note, It looks to me the only way to handle these mismatching number of columns (becuae of which I have to filter rowsets) in usql is:

1. Filter your data for the given columns. Like the one I am asking about in the question.
2. Use Dynamic Columns, like select A["Data"] as A["Name"]? Strangely U-SQL asks you to name the columns before hand, it would have been an amazing feature otherwise.

Any other approach you see to handle: any number of columns in files, missing columns, mismatched number of columns among different JSON files?

Sample Input:

```
[
  {
    "PID": "10201820",
    "System": [
      {
        "Name": "EventName",
        "Value": "SystemEvent"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Name",
        "Value": "Test"
      },
    ],
    "Domain": [
      {
        "Name": "Type",
        "Value": "ENTER"
      },
      {
        "Name": "startTime",
        "Value": "1/10/2018 11:21:10 AM"
      }
    ],
    "Custom": [
      {
        "Name": "platform",
        "Value": "Windows"
      },
      {
        "Name": "sys:eventts",
        "Value": "2018-01-10T11:21:10.440Z"
      },
      {
        "Name": "sys:mguid",
        "Value": "e236426e-a246-3e99f4f9bf95"
      },

      {
        "Name": "bus:AS2",
        "Value": "TestAs2From"
      },
      {
        "Name": "bus:AS3",
        "Value": "TestAs2To"
      },
      {
        "Name": "bus:Message-ID",
        "Value": "efd4-46bf-b11d-d838b4540aba"
      }
    ],
    "ttl": 8640000
  },



 {
    "PID": "201870",
    "System": [
      {
        "Name": "EventName",
        "Value": "SystemEvent"
      }
    ],
    "Domain": [
      {
        "Name": "Type",
        "Value": "ENTER"
      }
    ],
    "Custom": [
      {
        "Name": "sys:MachineName",
        "Value": "TestMachine"
      },
      {
        "Name": "cor:OriginalMessageId",
        "Value": "336-b102-4002-a7cc-36132e97"
      }
    ],
    "ttl": 8640000
  },

  {Similar rows as the one above just with some fields missing, some added}
]
```

Sample Output:

```
All Data Fields (CSV): PID System.EventName System.Name Custom.Type ...TTL

 ...Corresponding Values or 0 if field not present in a row of the json ...................
```

Comment: As I and others have asked in other related threads: Please provide a simple input file and the expected output. Your question is very broad and hard to answer. Since you can select any data from your JSON document into a rowset, you can then just use relational filters on the extracted rows. For example, you can use the `JsonFunctions.JsonTuple` to extract the value inside your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also, U-SQL - as all other SQL languages - do not provide you with dynamic column names. You will either have to pack the dynamic key/value pairs into a SqlMap or explicitly name them. there are examples for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362635/u-sql-error-in-naming-the-column

Comment: @MichaelRys Hi Michael, thanks for the replies. My data is formatted rather poorly, but cant change that. I have given the exact input output pair in the EDIT.  My issue is that my query fails in the case the data does not fit into my schema... i don't really know how many coluns will be there..i don't know what the column names will be there for sure...that's why I was trying to filter... please take a look at how to get the json data into flat csv files. thanls for your help.

Comment: @MichaelRys plz let me know if i could add any more details. thanks.

Comment: Thanks... do you know apriori what the event names are that you can encounter? Also, as I said in a different thread: This is one of the worst way of managing key/value pairs in JSON. The whole point of semistructured formats like JSON is that you can use the name as the property name and the value as the property value. Is there a chance to have your JSON format simplified at the source?

Comment: @MichaelRys thx, bit i have Gbs of data like this. Can't change the files.  Yes apriori I can look into files and get some field names that I must have in the csv. That's why I was trying to filter the rowset.

Comment: @MichaelRys yes, i do know a priori what event names i can encounter. its just that some will be missing. the awkward formatting of json is causing trouble. could you share a script with this data as a sample. thanks a lot for the help.